# how to redirect to new page after jquery ajax call in MVC if session timeout?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, redirect, session-timeout

1- I have an Ajax link that call an action and that action returns a view , that view open in a specific Div (consider it as a menu that update the div with the corresponding view)
2- if session timeout the returned my logon view

so if i click on the link and session is timeout , the log on view open in the div not in the whole page

what i should do so if the session timeout it return logon view in new page in on my div?

Answer (score 11):

An efficient way to handle a session expiry is to create a custom Authorization attribute and return a **HTTP 403** response if the session has expired and were dealing with an ajax request.

To create an Ajax aware authorization attribute you can inherit from **AuthorizeAttribute** and override the **HandleUnauthorizedRequest** event with a check on the type of request eg. **IsAjaxRequest()**

```
public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // Fire back an unauthorized response
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        }
        else
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then just decorate your controllers or actions with the AjaxAuthorize attribute just as you normally would with Authorize

```
[AjaxAuthorize(Roles = "1,2,3,4,5")]
public class HomeController 
{
```

Then if you're using jQuery you can handle the 403 response by creating a global ajax error handler.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function (x, e) {
            if (x.status == 403) {
                alert("Sorry, your session has expired. Please login again to continue");
                window.location = "/login";
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to login page on Session_Start event in Global

```
protected void Session_Start()
    {
        GeneRateKey();
        if (Session["Username"] != null)
        {
            //Redirect to Welcome Page if Session is not null  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/WelcomeScreen", false);

        }
        else
        {
            //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires                   
            new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Index" }, { "controller", "Login" } });
        }
    }
```