# How to redirect an Ajax Method session on timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I got a ajax method that returns a JSON result, but part of the method is to check if the session is valid.

So If a user refreshed a page, the ajax method is called, in which it throws an exception as the session has expired, now the method wants to return a JSON result, but instead I want to redirect them to the login page.

how do I do this?

```
public JsonResult GetClients()
{
var usertoken = new UserToken(this.User.Identity.Name);
if (usertoken.AccountId != null)
{
return new JsonResult() {Data = model, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
}
else
{
 //Redirect Here
}
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102964/how-to-redirect-to-new-page-after-jquery-ajax-call-in-mvc-if-session-timeout

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you would only be able to do this via JavaScript since your call is using ajax, the solution to the other post would not work since the redirect header would not be honored for an ajax request.

You might want to add a status or hasExpire property to your return result:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetClients()
{
var usertoken = new UserToken(this.User.Identity.Name);
if (usertoken.AccountId != null)
{
return Json(new { data = model, status = true });
}
else
{
  return Json(new { data = null, status = false });
}
```

On your ajax call:

```
$.ajax('/controller/getclients', { }, function(data) {
  if(data.status == true) {
    // same as before you've got your model in data.data...
  } else {
    document.location.href = '/account/login';
  }
});
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller code, check for session validity. For example

```
        if (Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logOffUrl"].ToString(),
                isTimeout = true
            });
        }
```

In .js file check like the following

```
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != '' && typeof data != 'undefined') {
            if (data.isTimeout) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
                return;
            }
```